# How to make 2 divs responsive with Position Absolute?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

**I got the following structure**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="html5">
     <h3>HTML5</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="pc"></div>
    </div>
```

**And the CSS**

```
.pc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 81%;
    left: 38%;
    width: 321px;
    height: 240px;
    background-image: url('images/pc.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
.html5 {
    width: 321px;
    height: 240px;
    background-image: url('images/1.png');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44%;
    left: 27%;
}
```

I want to put my `.html5` positined in a certain point to `.pc`, is there any way to make it responsive so when resizing the web page I can still maintain it in the same distance to the other div?

I'm using `bootstrap`, don't know if there is any trick with one of his classes.[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fetoexs/)

Comment: Can you please provide us some fiddle?

Comment: Can you put `.html5` div inside `.pc` div?

Comment: not clear your asked question, can you please explain more about it

Comment: Yes, sorry, I want to keep my background-image in .html5 always at the left corner of .pc div, so then when I resize the browser both divs can maintain their position

Comment: @ArnauSilvestreDulcet It can be done, widths/heights/top/left all need to be defined in percentages though, relative to the container. What is it supposed to look like anyway?

Comment: @partypete25 it was just a test for a website to put the first div in a certain point above the other div and then keep the relation, will try what you said, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can't with the current structure. I'd suggest something like this, and position .html5 relative to .pc.

```css
.pc {
  position: absolute; 
  ...
}

.html5 {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pc">
    <div class="html5">
      <h3>HTML5</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks it worked! if you don't mind, I'm pretty newbi here, so what is the diference to my approach and yours?

Comment: In your approach, you create two sibling divs. When you add the absolute positioning, they no longer know about each others' dimensions and position, so you can't position them relatively to each other. In the approach with the nested div, the child can be positioned relatively to its parent because it's 0,0 coordinates is the top left corner of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the initial solution, but if you are working with bootstrap then you need to add it's library and some pre-defined classes. Another option to make it responsive is using media query.

```
.pc {
 width: 321px;
height: 240px;
background-image: url('http://cremc.ponce.inter.edu/carpetamagica/cuadradoquisosercirculo_files/image001.gif');
background-size: cover;
float:left;
margin-left:10%;
margin-top:10%;
}
.html5 {
width: 321px;
height: 240px;
background-image: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fId_0wMCKhg/Tz8dxylpK2I/AAAAAAAAJCE/7gF4evDn5zo/s1600/que%2Bes%2Bun%2Btriangulo.jpg');
background-size: cover;
float:left;
margin-left:10%;
margin-top:10%;
}
```